# cv2.waitKey(0) doen't wait

Tags: python, opencv

```
key = cv2.waitKey(0)
print(key)
>>>-1
```

I have known that "cv2.waitKey(0)" wait and code does nothing until any key is pressed.

how can I make "cv2.waitKey(0)" work??

Comment: What are you trying to do? are you planning to show an image or ?

Answer (score 0):

from the [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#cv.WaitKey) cv2.waitKey(delay) waits for `delay` milliseconds and also,  The function only works if there is at least one HighGUI window created and the window is active.

It returns the code of the pressed key or -1 if no key was pressed before the specified time had elapsed.

You didn't press anything. that's why you get the -1

Comment: I saw that as 'cv2.waitKey' example. so I coded the same but it didn't work, asking here.